# Server side varification after client side done

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Suppose i have a login form where two form elements i.e username and password. But in client side verification i am not set required option in username. My target is after make client side verification i want to varify this from server side through ajax, where username field will be verified in server side,if username is blank then php check and response as a json. I want to parse the data and show the validation error and also show if login authentication error message to different div element in login form. But could not get this. Please help me with this issue.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        // initialize validator and add the custom form submission logic
            $("#LoginForm").validator().submit(function(e) {

                    var form = $(this);

                    // client-side validation passed
                        if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {


                            $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: "process.login.php",
                                data: $('#LoginForm').serialize(),
                                dataType: "json",
                                success: function(msg){

                                    if(parseInt(msg.status)==1)
                                        {   
                                            window.location=msg.txt;
                                        }
                                 }
                            });


                            // prevent default form submission logic
                            e.preventDefault();
                        }
                    });

                });
```

Comment: You have a missing } in success: function(msg){

Comment: thanks, updated this code.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to know how the php (server) validation response work?

```
<?php

// your validation here ...

$msg = array("status"=>1, "text"=>"some text here");

echo json_encode($msg);
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help.. I had to spoof your response in the hidden form variable but you should grab message and status and handle it. Also catch for server side errors.

I also fixed your validation the way you had it set up but you may want to read the documentation on the best practices for jQuery validator.

http://jsfiddle.net/Xedus129/y6fA3/

error handling/success handling in the ajax call :

```
            success: function (msg) {
                var status = parseInt(msg.status);
                var message = msg.message;
                return handleResponse(status,message);
            },

            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                //this is a fatal error
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(thrownError);
            }
```

Hopefully this is what you were asking, hard to tell from your question.

Comment: I have done client side validation on password field, i.e jquery check if the password field is blank or not. If blank then show the error message(default validation error msg) or else use this one 'if ($(this).valid()) {' and post to the php page, where name field will be checked if blank then it throw a msg in json format, and passed to the jquery validator like {'username':'enter the username'}